# minimum in list of lists in prolog

Tags: list, prolog, minimum

hello i have a list like this:

```
[[3,[a,b,c,d]],[2,[a,b,d]],[5,[d,e,f]]]
```

list of lists...
i want to find the minimum number on inner list
in this case i want to return D=2 and L=[a,b,d]

i tried this code:

```
minway([[N|L]],N,L).
minway([[M|L1]|L2],D,_):- M<D, minway(L2,M,L1).
minway([[M|_]|L2],D,L):- M>=D, minway(L2,D,L).
```

but i got error:

```
</2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
   Exception: (8) minway([[3,[a,b,c,d]],[2,[a,b,d]],[5,[d,e,f]]], _G7777, _G7778) ? 
   creep
```

for this run sentence:

```
minway([[3,[a,b,c,d]],[2,[a,b,d]],[5,[d,e,f]]],D,L).
```

the result need to be:

```
D=2.
L=[a,b,d].
```

where my problem?
and how to fix it?

tnx a lot

Answer (score 2):

First, switch to a better data representation: Instead of `[Key,Value]`, use `Key-Value`!

Then, define `minway_/3` based on 
[`iwhen/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40449516/4609915),
[`ground/1`](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/mpg_002dref_002dground.html),
[`keysort/2`](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/mpg_002dref_002dkeysort.html), and
[`member/2`](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/mpg_002dref_002dmember.html), like so:

```
minway_(Lss, N, Ls) :-
   iwhen(ground(Lss), (keysort(Lss,Ess), Ess = [N-_|_], member(N-Ls, Ess))).
```

Sample query using SICStus Prolog 4.5.0:

```
| ?- minway_([3-[a,b,c,d],2-[a,b,d],5-[d,e,f],2-[x,t,y]], N, Ls).
N = 2, Ls = [a,b,d] ? ;
N = 2, Ls = [x,t,y] ? ;
no
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of fundamental issues.

One is in your problem lies in your representation of a list. Your predicates seem to assume that, for example, `[3, [a,b,c]]` is represented as `[3 | [a,b,c]]` but it is not. The list `[3 | [a,b,c]]` is the list with `3` as the head, and `[a,b,c]` as the rest of the list or the tail. In other words, `[3 | [a,b,c]]` is `[3, a, b, c]`.

And, so, your base case would be:

```
minway([[N,L]], N, L).
```

The second issue is in your other predicate clauses. There's no starting point for `D`. In other words, it's never given a value to start with, so you get an instantiation error. You cannot compare `N > D` if one of the variables doesn't have a value.

When doing a minimum or maximum from scratch, a common approach is to start by assuming the first element is the candidate result, and then replace it if you find a better one on each step of the recursion. It also means you need to carry with you the last candidate at each recursive call, so that adds extra arguments:

```
minway([[N,L]|T], D, R) :-
    minway(T, N, L, D, R).

minway([], D, R, D, R).            % At the end, so D, R is the answer
minway([[N,L]|T], Dm, Rm, D, R) :-
    (   N < Dm
    ->  minway(T, N, L, D, R)      % N, L are new candidates if N < Dm
    ;   minway(T, N, Dm, Rm, D, R) % Dm, Rm are still best candidate
    ).
```

In Prolog, you can simplify this a little since Prolog has a more general term comparison operator, `@<`, `@>`, etc, which is smart about comparing more complex terms. For example, `[2, [d,e,f]] @< [3, [a,b,c]]` is true since `2 < 3` is true. We can then write:

```
minway([H|T], D, R) :-
    minway(T, H, D, R).

minway([], [D, R], D, R).
minway([H|T], M, D, R) :-
    (   H @< M
    ->  minway(T, H, D, R)
    ;   minway(T, M, D, R)
    ).
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the minimum predicate. Findall can be very helpful.

```
min([X],X).
min([H|T],Min):-
    min(T,TMin),
    H>TMin,
    Min is TMin.
min([H|T],Min):-
    min(T,TMin),
    H=<TMin,
    Min is H.

minway(List,D,L):-
    findall(Value,member([Value,_],List),VList),
    min(VList,Min),
    D=Min,
    findall(EList,member([Min,EList],List),L).

?-minway([[3,[a,b,c,d]],[2,[a,b,d]],[5,[d,e,f]]],D,L).
D = 2,
L = [[a, b, d]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try library(aggregate):

```
?- aggregate_all(min(X,Y), 
       member([X,Y], [[3,[a,b,c,d]],
                      [2,[a,b,d]],
                      [5,[d,e,f]]]), 
       min(D,L)).
D = 2,
L = [a, b, d].
```

See also here:

**Aggregation operators on backtrackable predicates**
https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate